# Solving the integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^n e^{-ax^2+bx} \, dx$... Moments of anormal distribuition?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions

I'm trying to find a closed formula for the integral in $(eq. 1)$, but i wasn't able to do anything. On the other hand, while searching on the web i found a closed formula for the cases $(n=1, \, n=2)$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions).. but there isn't any demonstration. Moreover, i found that these integrals could correspond to '$n$-th moment' of a normal distribuition, but then again i hadn't found anything else.

---

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^n e^{-ax^2+bx} \, dx \longrightarrow a \in \mathbb{R^+}, \, b\in \mathbb{C} \qquad (1)$$

Comment: Just complete the square in the exponential.  Then you have moments of the normal distribution.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Ok, very well.. can i ask you to follow my reasoning? I managed to show that: $\left[e^{-ax^2+bx}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}} \text{ } n(\mu, \text{ } \sigma^2)\right]$ where $\left[ \text{  } n(\mu, \text{ } \sigma^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right]$ with $\left[ \text{  } \mu = \frac{b}{2a} \text{ and } \sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2a} \right]$

Comment: At this point can i say that: $\left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^n \text{ } e^{-ax^2 + bx} \text{ } dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^n \text{ } n(\mu, \text{ } \sigma^2) \text{ } dx = 
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}} \mathbb{E}[x^n] \right]$ where {$\mathbb{E}[x^n]$} is the $n$-th moment of a normal distribuition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After completing the square
$$
I_n=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^ne^{-a x^2+bx}\,\mathrm dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{b^2/4a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^n \phi(x;b/2a,1/2a)\,\mathrm dx,
$$
where $\phi(x;\mu,\sigma^2)$ is the normal probability density. Thus
$$
I_n=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{b^2/4a}\mathsf EX^n
$$
with $X\sim\mathcal N(b/2a,1/2a)$. Using equation 18 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.08790) (you can probably find this elsewhere) the integer moments of the normal variable can be expressed in terms of Hermite polynomials giving
$$
I_n=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{b^2/4a}\left(\frac{i}{2\sqrt a}\right)^nH_n\left(-i\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}\right),
$$
where $i$ is the imaginary unit (this will yield a real solution for all nonnegative integers $n$). Here is a table of the first few values
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & I_n\\
 0 & \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{\frac{1}{a}} e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}} \\
 1 & \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{3/2} b
   e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}} \\
 2 & \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{5/2}
   \left(2 a+b^2\right) e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}} \\
 3 & \frac{1}{8} \sqrt{\pi } \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{7/2} b
   \left(6 a+b^2\right) e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}} \\
 4 & \frac{1}{16} \sqrt{\pi } \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{9/2}
   \left(12 a^2+12 a b^2+b^4\right) e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In fact, you can extend this integral to negative integer $n$ using a regularization technique found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4083413/did-i-find-a-generating-function-for-assigning-values-to-mathsf-ex-n-x-s).

If you're interested in the case for $b=0$ we may use the well-known [explicit expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Special_values) for $H_n(0)$ giving
$$
I_n\big|_{b=0}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\left(\frac{i}{2\sqrt a}\right)^nH_n(0)%
=
\begin{cases}
0, &n\ \text{ odd}\\
\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\frac{(n-1)!!}{(2 a)^{n/2}}, &n\ \text{ even}.
\end{cases}
$$

**Edit:**

OP has asked for clarification.  Once we have $I_n$ in terms of moments of the normal distribution, all we need is an explicit expression for those moments.  One quick way to do this is to compare the moment generating function
$$
M_X(t)=e^{bt/2a+t^2/4a}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(\mathsf EX^n)\frac{t^n}{n!}
$$
to the generating function for the Hermite polynomials
$$
e^{2xt-t^{2}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }H_{n}(x){\frac {t^{n}}{n!}}.
$$

Comment: Your answer is really nice! Since it adds complexity to the topic, but it seems it goes beyond my capabilities.. Infact, i should demonstrate the fromula you provide in $(eq.18)$, but i can't really understand it (i refer to the demonstration itself, i know what hermite polynomial are). This is why prefer a simpler solution like the one provided by @Quanto. But it would be great if you could provide an explaination of $(eq.18)$ or another method to evaluate the $n$-th moment of a normal distribuition.. like a source where is wrtitten the explicit solution of the integral.

Answer (score 2):

**Suggestion**:

First, evaluate

$$I_0(a,b)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2+bx} \, dx
= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \ e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}}
$$
Then
$$I_n(a,b) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^n e^{-ax^2+bx} \, dx
= \frac{d^n}{db^n}I_0(a,b)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \frac{d^n (e^{\frac{b^2}{4a}})}{db^n}
$$
and, in particular
\begin{align}
&J_1= \frac{d}{db} I_0(a,b) = I_0\frac b{2a}\\
 &J_2= \frac{d}{db}I_1(a,b)=I_0
 \left(\frac1{2a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2} \right)\\
&J_3= \frac{d}{db}I_2(a,b)=I_0\bigg(\cdots\bigg)
\end{align}

Comment: I'm really glad to read such an answer, in fact it was my very first attempt (since i already knew the value of the integral)!! But, i must be very tired or very dumb, considering (at this point i know for sure) that i committed a mistake somewhere, and i kept to reiterate it!! :D Anyway, i'm really grateful with you for your elegant solution.

Comment: Anyway, would you discuss about the other method i was following with @AaronHendrickson (read my comments above)? I mean, the final results are totally the same, but let's suppose that $b=0$.. in the AaronHendrickson's solution i can easily see that the only difference is $(\mu \rightarrow 0)$.. On the other hand, how could your solution still be well-defined?

Comment: @giuliolib - you may still differentiate wrt $b$ and then let $b=0$ afterwards

Answer (score 1):

If you enjoy  Kummer confluent hypergeometric function
$$2\, a^{\frac{n+2}{2}}\,I_n=\sqrt{a} \,\left(1+(-1)^n\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{b^2}{4 a}\right)+$$
$$b\, \left(1-(-1)^n\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right) \,
   _1F_1\left(\frac{n+2}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{b^2}{4 a}\right)$$

Comment: Who doesn't enjoy a good hypergeometric solution? Cheers.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson. Hi, stranger !

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $$M_n=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^ne^{-(x-m)^2/2\sigma^2}\frac{dx}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}=\mathbb{E}(X^n)$$ where $X\sim N(m,\sigma^2)$ has the same distribution as $m+\sigma Z$ where $Z\sim N(0,1).$ Remember also that
$$\mathbb{E}(Z^{2k})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}z^{2k}e^{-z^2/2}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{2\pi}}=\frac{2^k}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{k-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{2^k}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(k+\frac{1}{2}).$$ Of course $\mathbb{E}(Z^{2k+1})=0.$ This gives a way to compute
$$M_n=\mathbb{E}((m+\sigma Z)^n)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}C^i_n\sigma^i\mathbb{E}(Z^i)m^{n-i}.$$

Now, what is the link with $I_n=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^ne^{-ax^2+bx}dx?$ Well, $I_n=CM_n$ with $a=1/(2\sigma^2)$  and suitable $b$ and $C$ that you can compute by yourself.