# Discrete random walk/risk process characterized by a step distribution with a heavy tail and a mean existing only as a Hadamard finite-part integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk, queueing-theory, cauchy-principal-value, risk-assessment

This question is an attempt to make more precise two previous questions of mine on another SE ([this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/536224/the-meaning-of-an-analytical-result-concerning-the-formally-nonexistent-mean-o) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538401/a-follow-up-to-the-meaning-of-an-analyt-result-concerning-the-mean-of-the-squ)).

### The random walk/risk process of interest

Consider the following discerete process. Let $n=1,\,2,\,3,\,\ldots$. Define
$$\hspace{8em}R_{n}=u+c\,n-\sum_{j=1}^{n}V_{j}\,,\hspace{8em}(1)$$
where

1. The $V_{j}$'s are independent identically distributed random variables (i.i.d. RVs). Namely, for all $j=1,\,2,\,3,\,\ldots$, we have that $V_{j}=1/X_{j}^{2},$ where the $X_{j}$ are  i.i.d. RVs whose common distribution is $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma)$, the normal distribution with a mean $\mu$ and a standard deviation $\sigma>0$.  **We will require that** $\boldsymbol{\mu\neq 0}$. Using standard methds, one can work out that probability density function of the distribution from which the $V_{j}$'s are drawn in
2. Note that the $V_{j}$'s are arriving at regularly spaced intervals. This is different than in the standard Cramér–Lundberg model (see e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Heavy_Tailed_and_Sube/BSY_AAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22In+context+of+the+collective+theory+of+risk,+we+consider+the+classical%22&pg=PA130&printsec=frontcover)).
3. $u\geqslant 0$ is a fixed (i.e. independent of $n$) real number. (I suspect it won't matter much for what interests me.)
4. $c=(\eta+1)\mu_{V}$.
5. $\mu_{V}>0$ is a fixed real number.
6. $\eta>0$ is a fixed real number.

If the $V_{j}$'s had a finite mean, i.e. if the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}dx$ existed, then $\mu_{V}$ would be equal to it. But that integral doesn't exist, not even in the [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cauchy_principal_value&oldid=1032684393) sense (whereas the mean value of $1/x$ does exist in the principal value sense; more on that below).

My primary conjecture is that (for all nonzero $\mu$ and $\sigma$) there exists a number to which $\mu_{V}$ can be set such that the 'sharpened conjecture' (see below) is true. (If that is so, then it might make sense to call $\mu_{V}$ a 'pseudo-mean' or a 'quasi-mean' of the $V_{j}$', or something like that.)

My secondary conjecture is that if the primary conjecture is true, then $\mu_{V}$ is in fact **the Hadamard finite part** of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}dx$. It is given below in Eq. (9) and, in a different form, in Eqs. (4) and (10); I will denote it $\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}$. For more on the Hadamar finite part, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_regularization). As I will discuss below, $\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}$ is analytically computable in terms of the [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dawson_function&oldid=1033812104) $F(x)=e^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt$ as
$$\hspace{5em}\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}=\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\, \mu}{\sigma}F\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}\,\sigma}\right)-1\right).\hspace{5em}(2)$$
(So my secondary conjecture is that $\mu_{V}=\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}$.)

### Interpretation in the context of ruin theory

In the context of [*ruin theory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruin_theory),

1. $R_{n}$ is the reserve of the insurance company at time $n$ ('ruin' occurs if $R_{n}$ turns negative);
2. $u=R_{0}$ is the initial reserve;
3. $c>0$ is the rate of inflow of premium;
4. the $V_{j}$'s are claim sizes; and
5. $\eta$ is the *safety loading* (see e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Risk_and_Insurance/w63dDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22and+for+this+reason+denoted+the+safety+loading%22&pg=PA86&printsec=frontcover));

As usual, we will introduce the notion of ***ruin time*** $n_{\text{R}}$ (which in our case is a positive integer) as follows. For any given realization of the process $R_{n}$, $n_{\text{R}}$ is the lowest $n>0$ such that $R_{n}<0$.

### The Hadamard finite part

The main complication in my case is that the claims come from a distribution whose tail is so heavy that the mean value doesn't exist even in a [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cauchy_principal_value&oldid=1032684393) sense, but only in **the Hadamard finite part** sense. Using standard methods, one can show that he probability density function for the $V_{j}$'s is
$$\hspace{4em}p(z)=\frac{1}{z^{3/2}}\frac{1}{2\,
   \sqrt{2 \pi }\, \sigma}\Big(e^{-\frac{1}{2 \sigma
   ^2}(\mu +1/\sqrt{z})^{2}}+e^{-\frac{1}{2 \sigma
   ^2}(\mu -1/\sqrt{z})^{2}}\Big)\,.\hspace{4em}(3)$$
We see that the meain value $\int_{0}^{\infty}z\,p(z)\,dz$ doesn't exit because $z\,p(z)$ goes to zero only as $1/\sqrt{z}$ for large $z$. Note that this same (nonexistent) mean value may also be written as $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}dx$, a form in which it is more obvious how we might try to use the principal value; for example, the mean value of $1/X$,  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}dx$, does exist in the principal value sense. Indeed, I will use this latter fact in the Appendix, where I show that **the Hadamard finite part** of the mean value integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}z\,p(z)\,dz$ is
$$\hspace{2em}\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}=
\int_{0}^{\infty}z\,\left(p(z)-{C}/{z^{3/2}}\right)\,dz=\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\, \mu}{\sigma}F\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}\,\sigma}\right)-1\right)\,,\hspace{2em}(4)
$$
where $C={\displaystyle\lim_{s\to+\infty}} s^{3/2}p(s)$.

As a comparison, in the case of e.g. the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), a prototypical example of a heavy-tailed distribution, the mean value does exist in the principal value sense; see e.g. the footnote [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Randomness_and_Hyper_randomness/jaUzDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Cauchy+distribution%22+%22principal+value%22&pg=PA43&printsec=frontcover).

### Motivation: a vague conjecture

My hope is that this random walk/risk process will make possible a precise formulation of the following vague conjecture:

> **Vague conjecture:** As $n$ grows larger and larger, the average $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}V_{j}$ gets closer and closer to $\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}$ **until** the latest $V_{j}$ suffers a single catastrophic jump.

### Numerical evidence for the vague conjecture

This is indeed what I see in numerical simulations with $\mu=0.60$ and $\sigma=0.10$, which results in $\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}=3.05003$. Here is my procedure.

(1) Draw a sample $\left\{x_{j}\right\}_{j=1}^{N}$ of $N=10^{8}$ points from $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma)$ (that's close to the maximal $N$ that my laptop can handle).
(2) Define the sample $\left\{v_{j}\right\}_{j=1}^{N}$ by setting $v_{j}=1/x_{j}^{2}$. 
 (3) Check whether  $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}v_{j}$ differs from $\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}$ by more than $\eta\, \mu_{V}^{\text{H}}$, where $\eta=10^{-3}$. 
(4) If it doesn't, go back to (1). If it does, stop, and produce a plot of $\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}v_{j}\right)$ vs. $n$ for $n=1,\,2,\,\ldots,\,N$. Here is a typical plot that comes out (only every millionth point is plotted, and I start from $n/10^{6}=3$, omitting an initial transient):

[image]

Here the sample maximum was about $v_{j_{\text{max}}}\approx 2\times10^{6}$, while the second-largest value was about 800. The maximum occurred at $j_{\text{max}}\approx 65\times10^{6}$ in the sample and caused the catastrophic jump away from $\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}$ that is visible in the plot.

The discrepancy criterion of $\eta=10^{-3}$ was chosen by experimentation. For larger discrepancies (e.g. $10^{-2}$), it takes too long to produce a plot—too many cycles from (3) to (1). For smaller discrepancies (e.g. $10^{-4}$), there isn't a manifest single jump away from $\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}$.

### How a sharpened conjecture (a more precise formulation of the vague conjecture) *might* look like, in terms of the random walk/risk process

Intuitively, we need $n$ to be large enough so that the 'non-catastrophic' fluctuations in $V_{j}$'s get averaged out. But we also need to condition this on the assumption that the first catastrophic jump hasn't happened yet.

We will use the notion of ruin time $n_{\text{R}}$ (which we introduced above) to characterize 'catastrophic jumps'. Both the numerics and general experience with heavy-tailed distributions suggest that in the presence of heavy tails, ruin occurs as a result of a single big step (see e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Risk_and_Insurance/w63dDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22With+heavy+tails,+the+intuition+is+that+of+one+big+jump.%22&pg=PA98&printsec=frontcover)).

Then I suspect that the following is (a) true and (b) a good candidate for a rigorous version of the vague conjecture above:

> **Sharpened conjecture:**
>
> **Primary conjecture:** Set $u=0$. For every $\mu\neq 0$ and every $\sigma>0$, there exists a $\mu_{V}>0$ such that the following holds.
>
> For every $\eta>0$, no matter how small, and every $\epsilon>0$, no matter how small, there exists a sufficiently large $n^{*}>0$ such that if $n_{\text{R}}> n^{*}$, then for every $n$ such that $n^{*}\leqslant n < n_{\text{R}}$, the probability that $\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}V_{j}-\mu_{V}\right|<\eta\,\mu_{V}$ is at least $1-\epsilon$.
>
> **Secondary conjecture:** If the primary conjecture is true, then $\mu_{V}=\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}$.

The primary conjecture is kind of inspired by Theorem 10.7.2 [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Stochastic_Networks/uwHrBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Next+consider+the+problem+of+formulating+and+showing+that+the+random+walk+behaves+in+its+typical+way+except+for+the+big+jump.%22&pg=PA208&printsec=frontcover) (and, if true, would correspond to some sort of a baby version of that theorem).

## My questions

**1. Is it the case that the 'sharpened conjecture' is both true and a good candidate for a rigorous version of the 'vague conjecture'? What would it take to prove it?** 
**2. If not, is there a statement that ***is*** both true and a good candidate for a rigorous version of the 'vague conjecture'? (It doesn't have to necessarily be stated in the language of random walks or risk processes.)**

### Prior research

It is hard to believe that what I'm asking isn't well-known.

However, extensive searches on google and google books for keywords 'random walk', 'Hadamard finite part', and 'heavy tail' have so far turned up nothing.

Of course processes similar to my $R_{n}$ are studied in risk/ruin theory, queuing theory, and related fields. In these fields, the processes under study are in one sense typically more complicated than my $R_{n}$, because the $V_{j}$'s are not equally spaced but arrive as a Poisson process. But in another sense their processes are usually simpler, because normally $V_{j}$'s are assumed to have a well-defined mean value even if they have a heavy tail (e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Risk_and_Insurance/w63dDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22and+for+this+reason+denoted+the+safety+loading%22&pg=PA86&printsec=frontcover)). Nevertheless, models with infinite means have been studied. One example is D. Denisov, S. Foss, and D. Korshunov, 'Tail Asymptotics for the Supremum of a Random Walk when the Mean Is not Finite', Queueing Syst. **46,** 15–33 (2004) (published version [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FB%3AQUES.0000021140.87161.9c), arXiv version [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.4715)).

Nevertheless, so far I haven't found anything that would help me answer the questions I'm posing here.

### Appendix: How the Hadamard finite part comes in

Let $Y=1/X,$ where $X$ is a normally distributed random variable with a mean $\mu$ and a standard deviation $\sigma$. Note that the integral representing $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ (the mean value of $Y$) exists in the [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Cauchy_principal_value&oldid=1032684393) sense.
It may be related to the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform) of a Gaussian, which, in turn, is expressible in terms of the [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dawson_function&oldid=1033812104) $F(x)=e^{-x^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^{2}}dt$. For references, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Inverse_distribution&oldid=1029548102#Reciprocal_normal_distribution), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dawson_function&oldid=1033812104#Relation_to_Hilbert_transform_of_Gaussian), [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1021915128433) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368344/cauchy-principal-value-of-mathbbe1-x-x-sim-mathcaln-mu-sigma2?rq=1) on Mathematics SE. In the end, one obtains
$$\hspace{4em}\mathbb{E}[Y]=\text{P.V.}\;\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sigma}F\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}\,\sigma}\right)\,.\hspace{4em}(5)$$

Let us change variables, like so:
$$\text{P.V.}\;\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}dx = \text{P.V.}\;\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u+\mu}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}du\,.\hspace{4em}(6)$$

Next, we differentiate with respect to $\mu$. I will assume without proof that the differentiation commutes with the limit used to define the principal value (I don't have  a rigorous proof, but I do believe it is true). On the left-hand side, we get
$$\frac{d}{d\mu}\text{P.V.}\;\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}dx=\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}\left[1-\mu\left(\text{P.V.}\;\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}dx\right)\right]$$
$$\hspace{10em}=\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}\mu}{\sigma}F\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}\,\sigma}\right)\right)\,.\hspace{4em}(7)$$
When we differentiate on the right-hand side, we must take into account the fact that, unlike on the left-hand side, here $\mu$ appears in the limits of integration used to define the principal value:
$$\frac{d}{d\mu} \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\mu-\epsilon}\frac{1}{u+\mu}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}du+\int_{-\mu+\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{1}{u+\mu}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}du\right).$$
We get
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}} \left[\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\left(e^{-\frac{(\mu+\epsilon)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}+e^{-\frac{(\mu-\epsilon)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\right)\right.$$
$$\left.-\int_{-\infty}^{-\mu-\epsilon}\frac{1}{(u+\mu)^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}du-\int_{-\mu+\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(u+\mu)^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}du\right]\,.\hspace{2em}(8)$$
The first term, which comes from the differentiation of the limits of integration, diverges (when $\epsilon\to 0$) as $\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{\mu^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}$, and presumably exactly cancels the divergences from the two integrals that follow. Putting it all together, after changing variables once again and mupliplying both sides by $-1$, we get
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}} \left[\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}dx+\int_{\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}dx-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{\mu^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\right]$$
$$\hspace{10em}=\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}=\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\, \mu}{\sigma}F\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}\,\sigma}\right)-1\right)\,.\hspace{4em}(9)$$
The left-hand side of Eq. (9) is precisely **the Hadamard finite part** of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}dx$.

It may be useful to present this in yet another way. Using standard methods, we can show that the probability density function for $V=1/X^{2}$ is (this is Eq. (3) above)
$$p(z)=\frac{1}{z^{3/2}}\frac{1}{2\,
   \sqrt{2 \pi }\, \sigma}\Big(e^{-\frac{1}{2 \sigma
   ^2}(\mu +1/\sqrt{z})^{2}}+e^{-\frac{1}{2 \sigma
   ^2}(\mu -1/\sqrt{z})^{2}}\Big).$$
It is easy to see that $p(z)$ (defined for $z>0$) is heavy-tailed and that its mean value $\int_{0}^{\infty}z\,p(z)\,dz$ diverges, since $z\,p(z)$ goes to zero only as $1/\sqrt{z}$ for large $z$. But *Mathematica,* for example, can work out the following integral, which we obtain from the left-hand side of Eq. (9) after a change of variables and after bringing the third term on the left-hand side of Eq. (9) inside the integral:
$$\hspace{4em}
\mu_{V}^{\text{H}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}z\,\left(p(z)-\frac{1}{z^{3/2}}\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{\mu^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}\right)\,dz\,.\hspace{4em}(10)
$$
The result, of course, is the same as the right-hand side of Eq. (9), $=\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}\, \mu}{\sigma}F\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{2}\,\sigma}\right)-1\right)$.