# How the asymptotic expansions of the Dawson integral and $\exp(x^2)\operatorname {erfc}(x)$ were originally obtained?

Tags: calculus

There are two well known asymptotic expansions of the Dawson integral $F(x)$ and the function $\exp(x^2)\operatorname {erfc}(x)$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$:

$$
F(x)\sim (1/2)(1/x+1/(2x^3)+ 3/(4x^5)+\cdots)
$$
and
$$
\exp(x^2)\operatorname {erfc}(x)\sim(1/\sqrt{\pi})(1/x - 1/(2x^3) + 3/(4x^5)+\cdots).
$$

I am looking for the original publications where these expansions were derived for the first time. I would appreciate any pointers. I am also interested in any other publications dealing with the issue why the Laplace transformation cannot (or perhaps can?) be used to derive such expansions.

New stuff added 08.09.2022:
Your comments and suggestions are interesting, but I would like
to explain in more detail my motivations for submitting this post. My intention was to find some explanation to a certain paradox.

A well known result concerning the Laplace transform is

$\exp(t)\operatorname {erfc}(\sqrt{t})=L^{-1}\left\{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}\left(\sqrt{s}+1\right)}\right\} $.

where $s$ is the Laplace variable. It appears perfectly legal to
use this result for obtaining a series expansion of $\exp(x^{2})\operatorname{erfc}(x)$
around $x=0$. For this purpose one can employ the asymptotic expansion
of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}\left(\sqrt{s}+1\right)}$ for $s\rightarrow\infty$:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}\left(\sqrt{s}+1\right)}\sim s^{-1}-s^{-3/2}+s^{-2}-s^{-5/2}+s^{-3}-\ldots$

Laplace inverting this, term-by-term, gives

$\exp(t)\operatorname {erfc}(\sqrt{t})\sim1-(2\sqrt{t}/\sqrt{\pi})+t-4t^{3/2}/(3\sqrt{\pi})+t^{2}/2-\ldots$,

or equivalently,

$\exp(x^{2})\operatorname {erfc}(x)\sim1-2x/\sqrt{\pi}+x^{2}-4x^{3}/(3\sqrt{\pi})+x^{4}/2-\ldots$,

which is a correct expansion of $\exp(x^{2})\operatorname {erfc}(x)$ around $x=0$.

Now, let's examine if the same trick can be applied to obtain the
asymptotic expansion of $\exp(x^{2})\operatorname {erfc}(x)$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$.
Expand $\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}\left(\sqrt{s}+1\right)}$ around $s=0$:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}\left(\sqrt{s}+1\right)}\sim s^{-1/2}-1+s^{1/2}-s+s^{3/2}-s^{2}+\ldots$

Obviously, the term-by-term inversion cannot be performed in this
case, since except for the first two terms, the subsequent terms do
not possess the inverses. However, the formula for the inversion,
valid for $k<0$ is:

$L^{-1}\left\{ s^{k/2}\right\} =t^{-1-k/2}/\Gamma\left(-k/2\right)$.

If we incorrectly assume that this formula holds also for the case
$k>0$, then its application to the previous equation gives for $t>0$:

$\exp(t)\operatorname {erfc}(\sqrt{t})\sim(\pi t)^{-1/2}-t^{-3/2}/(2\sqrt{\pi})+3t^{-5/2}/(4\sqrt{\pi})+\ldots$

or, equivalently,

$\exp(x^{2})\operatorname {erfc}(x)\sim x^{-1}/\pi^{1/2}-x^{-3}/(2\sqrt{\pi})+3x^{-5}/(4\sqrt{\pi})+\ldots$

which miraculously happens to be the correct asymptotic expansion.
So, the question arises why we get a correct expansion by using an
incorrect procedure?! Or, maybe the procedure is not so incorrect
as it seems, but it has to be interpreted in some special (more abstract?)
way? Perhaps some generalization of the Laplace transformation has to be used? If anybody knows any explanation, I would appreciate an information.
I have to add that I observed a similar paradox with a number of other
functions.

Comment: 1) I don't understand your expressions : How are the first, second and third expressions connected ? Where is there an equal sign ? 2) Besides, give a reference about Dawson integral. 3) This kind of "historical" question could be asked on the cousin site hsm [history of science and mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7605/3730). 4) Please learn how to write formulas in Latex : for example here, I have changed a part into `1/\sqrt{\pi}`.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought in the case of asymptotic expansions one should use the "~" symbol instead of the equality symbol "=". If I am wrong, you can put "=" in the place of "~".  A basic reference to the Dawson integral is M. Abramowitz, I. Stegun, Handbook of Mathematical Functions, Dover, NY, Chapter 7.

Comment: Now that your question has been improved, it is very clear. Besides, thanks for the reference.

Comment: [$(7.7.1)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/7.7.E1) is a Laplace transform representation (with $z^2$ as the variable) and can be used together with Watson's lemma to derive the asymptotic expansion of $\operatorname{erfc}$. The expansion will in fact be valid in $|\arg z|<\frac{3\pi}{4}$ and thus can be used to obtain the expansion for Dawson's function as well.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but since there are no other answers, I thought I would post "a" probabilistic proof for the asymptotic expansion of Dawson's function. This is almost certainly not how the asymptotic expansion was originally obtained.

Let $X\sim\mathcal N(\sqrt 2,1/x^2)$. The expected value $\mathsf EX^{-1}$ is undefined; however, we can [assign it a value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368344/cauchy-principal-value-of-mathbbe1-x-x-sim-mathcaln-mu-sigma2/2369398#2369398) via the Cauchy principal value interpretation
$$
\mathsf{E}X^{-1}\overset{\text{p.v.}}{=}\lim_{\epsilon\nearrow 0}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}+\int_\epsilon^\infty\right)\frac{1}{t}f_X(t)\,\mathrm dt=\sqrt 2 xF(x),
$$
where $F(x):=e^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt$ is [Dawson's integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DawsonsIntegral.html). Notice that as $x\to\infty$, $\mathsf{Var}X\to 0$ and so we can use Taylor series to evaluate an asymptotic expansion for $\mathsf EX^{-1}$. Let $g(X)=1/X$. Expanding $g$ in a Taylor series about $\mathsf EX=\sqrt 2$ gives
$$
g(X)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{\sqrt 2-X}{\sqrt 2}\right)^k
$$
and so evaluating the expected value simply requires knowing central moments of the normal distribution. Evaluating the expected value termwise we find
$$
\mathsf Eg(X)
\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2x^2)^k}.
$$
Looking back at our expression for $\mathsf EX^{-1}$ it's clear that if we then divide $\mathsf Eg(X)$ by $\sqrt 2 x$ that we obtain an estimate for $F(x)$ at large $x$, namely,
$$
F(x)\sim\frac{1}{2x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2x^2)^k}=\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{4x^3}+\mathcal O(x^{-5}).
$$