# How to show $Var(T_n)=\infty$?

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, normal-distribution

This question is from George Casella Statistical Inference textbook question 10.5.

For the mean $\bar{X_n}$ of n iid normal observations with $EX=\mu$ and $VarX=\sigma^2$, if we take $T_n=\sqrt{n}/\bar{X_n}$

then show $Var(T_n)=\infty$.

The solution is :[image]

I don't quite understand this solution. Please see my process is correct or not. First, I need to know the pdf of $\bar{X_n}$, which is $n(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$. Hence,

$$E(T_n^2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{n}{x^2}*pdf=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{n}{x^2}\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}exp(-\frac{n(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2})$$.

Is my above step correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Then why in the solution, in the exp term, solution doesn't have n?

Comment: Does $E[T_n]$ exist?  If not, you can say $E[T_n^2]=\infty$ though perhaps not anything about $Var(T_n)$.  I also suspect  $E[T^2]> \cdots = \infty$ is slightly dubious

Comment: @Henry Both the question and the solution don't mention $E[T_n]$

Comment: @Yichuan The usual definition of the variance is the mean of the squared difference from the mean

Comment: @Henry I think here the solution uses variance = E(expectation^2) - expectation^2. So if the first term is infinity, then of course the variance is infinity.

Comment: It is not clear that expression for the variance is meaningful if there is no value finite or infinite for the expectation

Comment: @Henry You are correct. Claiming $\mathsf{Var}T_n=\infty$ is a nonsenical statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first show that $\mathsf E T_n^2=\infty$. Letting $T_n=\sqrt n/\bar X_n$ with $\bar X_n\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathsf ET_n^2
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{n}{x^2}f_{\bar X_n}(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{n}{x^2}f_{\bar X_n}(x)\,\mathrm dx}_{>0}+\int_0^1\frac{n}{x^2}f_{\bar X_n}(x)\,\mathrm dx+\underbrace{\int_1^\infty\frac{n}{x^2}f_{\bar X_n}(x)\,\mathrm dx}_{>0}\\
&>\int_0^1\frac{n}{x^2}f_{\bar X_n}(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\frac{n^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2}\underbrace{\exp\left(-\tfrac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2/n}\right)}_{\leq 1}\,\mathrm dx\\
&\geq\frac{n^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\infty,
\end{aligned}
$$
which completes the proof.

> Now comes a bit of controversy: Does this prove $\mathsf{Var}T_n=\infty$? **NO!!!**

Let me be clear that this has nothing to do with Casella's proof of $\mathsf{Var}T_n=\infty$ simply being incomplete. Instead, the **issue is that $\mathsf{Var}T_n$ is not infinite but rather undefined**. Let me explain:

Working directly from the definition of variance we have
$$
\mathsf{Var}T_n=\mathsf E T_n^2-(\mathsf ET_n)^2.
$$
It has already been shown that $\mathsf ET_n^2=\infty$ so the fact that $\mathsf{Var}T_n$ is undefined stems from $\mathsf ET_n$ being undefined. Why is this? Working from the definition of expected value for continuous random variables we write
$$
\mathsf ET_n=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sqrt n}{x}f_{\bar X_n}(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{\sqrt n}{x}f_{\bar X_n}(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt n}{x}f_{\bar X_n}(x)\,\mathrm dx=-\infty+\infty,
$$
which is indeterminant. This fact is due to $\lim_{x\to 0^-}x^{-1}=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^{-1}=\infty$ so the pole in the integrand at $x=0$ is what is causing problems. If we're clever, we may try to sneak up on the pole using limits as to cancel out the infinities in our problem. To do this we let $a,b,\epsilon>0$ and write
$$
\mathsf ET_n(a,b,\epsilon)=\int_{-\infty}^{-a\epsilon}\frac{\sqrt n}{x}f_{\bar X_n}(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_{b\epsilon}^\infty\frac{\sqrt n}{x}f_{\bar X_n}(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
and claim $\mathsf ET_n=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\mathsf ET_n(a,b,\epsilon)$. If there is any hope of $\mathsf ET_n$ being well-defined then $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\mathsf ET_n(a,b,\epsilon)$ should at least give the same value for any choice of $a,b$ (see disclaimer at end of question). Let's now do some numerical work. For the sake of simplicity let $\mu=1$, $\sigma=1$, $n=1$. Using Mathematica we numerically evaluate $\mathsf ET_n(a,b,\epsilon)$ for increasingly small values of $\epsilon$ to find:
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
\epsilon & \mathsf ET_n(1,1,\epsilon) &\mathsf ET_n(2,1,\epsilon) &\mathsf ET_n(3,1,\epsilon)\\
 10^{-1} & 0.676438 & 0.820142 & 0.894529 \\
 10^{-2} & 0.719939 & 0.885241 & 0.980932 \\
 10^{-3} & 0.724295 & 0.891774 & 0.989643 \\
 10^{-4} & 0.72473 & 0.892427 & 0.990514 \\
 10^{-5} & 0.724774 & 0.892493 & 0.990601 \\
 10^{-6} & 0.724778 & 0.892499 & 0.99061 \\
 10^{-7} & 0.724778 & 0.8925 & 0.99061 \\
 10^{-8} & 0.724778 & 0.8925 & 0.99061 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
And so we see that for different choices of $a,b$, $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\mathsf ET_n(a,b,\epsilon)$ converges to different (yet finite) values. In fact, using this approach gives a different answer for every choice of $a,b$! We thus conclude that $\mathsf ET_n$ and $\mathsf{Var}T_n$ are undefined.

**Small disclaimer:** Even if $\mathsf ET_n=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\mathsf ET_n(a,b,\epsilon)$ did yield the same solution for all $a,b$ this would still not be enough to prove that $\mathsf ET_n$ exists. We would instead need to show that
$$
\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^{-\delta}\frac{\sqrt n}{x}f_{\bar X_n}(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_{\epsilon}^\infty\frac{\sqrt n}{x}f_{\bar X_n}(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
converges (which it doesn't). The purpose of this example was to show how we can make the integral representation of $\mathsf ET_n$ "equal" to any value we want by changing $a,b$.

Comment: My thought process is that $\frac{\bar{X}}{\sqrt{n}}$ has a normal distribution with a positive density at $0$, so $T_n=\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\bar{X}}$ has undefined $E[T_n]$ and infinite $E[|T_n|]$,  and thus infinite $E[|T_n|^2]=E[T_n^2]$, but that rests on other results

Comment: @Henry Yes you are right. The issue lies in the fact that $T_n$ has positive density at the origin and so $T_n$ falls into the domain of attraction of the Cauchy distribution. Therefore, it cannot have well-defined mean and variance.

Comment: In your proof, can you explain in the 2nd line, why 2 terms are >0?

Comment: @Yichuan the integrand is positive on the entire real line so each of the three pieces must be positive. The integral of a positive function is always greater than zero.