# Question on limiting variance in example 10.1.8 (Casella, Statistical Inference, 2nd edition)

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

This is from George Casella textbook statistical inference (page 470) Example 10.1.8. Limiting variances. It says for the mean $\bar{X_n}$ of n iid normal observations with $EX=\mu$ and $VarX=\sigma^2$, if we take $T_n=\bar{X_n}$, then $lim\sqrt{n}Var\bar{X_n}=\sigma^2$ is the limiting variance of $T_n$.

I feel very confused. I think $\bar{X_n}$ is $n(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$. Then $lim\sqrt{n}*Var\bar{X_n}=lim\sqrt{n}*\sigma^2/n=\sigma^2lim\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=0$. The limit is 0, not $\sigma^2$.

Please point my mistake.

Comment: Just a hunch: maybe they really mean $\lim \text{Var}(\sqrt{n} \bar{X}_n)$?

Comment: @angryavian So you mean here is a typo in the textbook?

Comment: After looking at the book, my previous comment seems unlikely, given how "limiting variance" is defined. I'm guessing they meant $n \text{Var}(\bar{X}_n)$.

Comment: @angryavian Your hunch is correct. It is typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typo in the book. I have the same edition as you and upon opening my copy I see that I have already made this correction. We already know that $\mathsf{Var}\bar X_n=\sigma^2/n$. Using Casella's definition of *limiting variance* in definition 10.1.7 we can infer the sentence in Example 10.1.8 should read:

> ...if we take $T_n=\bar X_n$, then $\lim n\mathsf{Var}\bar X_n=\sigma^2$ is the limiting variance of $T_n$.

Indeed, using the same notation in the definition we have $k_n=n$, $T_n=\bar X_n$, and $\tau^2=\sigma^2$.

Comment: Thanks. I will wait for your check. My textbook is 2nd edition, page 470.

Comment: Another question on the same page: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159500/limiting-variances-of-iid-sample-mean

Comment: I also another question on this example. This is from the textbook question 10.5. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4075312/how-to-show-vart-n-infty?noredirect=1#comment8420931_4075312

Comment: @Yichuan See updated answer. I will address the other questions tomorrow.

Comment: So definition 10.1.7 is also wrong? It should be $lim Var(k_n T_n)$? But it still makes me confused. Since the definition is called the limiting variance of $T_n$, not limiting variance of a constant times $T_n$.

Comment: It is confusing. In fact, the whole of example 10.1.8 is very confusing! But I hope to bring some clarity in my answers to your other questions. There is nothing wrong with definition of limiting variance as given in Definition 10.1.7. In this particular case, $k_n=n$, $T_n=\bar X_n$, and $\tau^2=\sigma^2$. Sure, in this particular example, the limit isn't very interesting because it is the limit of a constant (i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sigma^2=\sigma^2$). Nonetheless, the example is still consistent with the definition.

Comment: Your word makes sense. Also, maybe question 10.5 can let you feel better of this example 10.1.8. I also asked this question in above links. Hopefully you can help me understand it! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Yichuan I answered the first question about problem 10.5 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4075312/how-to-show-vart-n-infty#comment8422189_4075312). Furthermore, I attempted to answer the other question you linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159500/limiting-variances-of-iid-sample-mean/4076234#4076234) although its a bit of an incoherent mess.